# How to execute if conditional just once

Tags: javascript

I am wondering me how I do that, because all the time the variable returns to your default value. It's an Ibeacon application, I don't know if I need to show more details about my app. I just want to call the function something once, can anyone help me?

```js
function uint8ArrToHexStringNoSpace(arr) {
 return Array.prototype.map.call(arr, function(n) {
  var s = n.toString(16);
  if(s.length == 1) {
   s = '0'+s;
  }
  return s;
 }).join('');
}

var quit;
function something() {
    if(quit) {
       window.open("info.html");
    } 
    quit = true;
}



function appendTd(root, value, id) {
 var text = document.createTextNode(value);
 var td = document.createElement("p");
 if(id) {
  td.id = id;
 }
 td.appendChild(text);
 root.appendChild(td);
}

function hex16(i) {
 var s = i.toString(16);
 while(s.length < 4) {
  s = '0'+s;
 }
 return s;
}



var beacons = {};

var app = {
 
 initialize: function() {
  // Important to stop scanning when page reloads/closes!
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e)
  {
   iBeacon.stopScan();
  });

  this.bindEvents();
  
 },
 bindEvents: function() {
  document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
 },
 onDeviceReady: function() {
  //app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
  app.startScan();
 },
 receivedEvent: function(id) {
  var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
  var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
  var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

  listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
  receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

  console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
 },


 
 startScan: function() {
  
  
  iBeacon.startScan({}, function(beacon) {
   //console.log("beacon found: "+beacon.address+" "+beacon.name+" "+beacon.rssi+"/"+beacon.txPower);
   var r = beacon.region;
   //console.log("M"+r.major.toString(16)+" m"+r.minor.toString(16)+" uuid "+uint8ArrToHexStringNoSpace(r.uuid));
   var key = 'tx'+beacon.address.replace(/:/g,'_');
   //console.log('key: '+key);
   
   
   
   
   if(beacons[key] == null) {
    beacons[key] = beacon;
    
    
    var root = document.getElementById("beaconListRoot");
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    
    // <tr><td>Address</td><td>Name</td><td>RSSI</td><td>ID</td><td>UUID</td></tr>
    var adress = '  Adress: ';
    var name = '  Name: ';
    var distance = '  distance: ';
    var major = '  Major: ';
    var minor = 'Minor: ';
    var UUID = '  UUID: ';
    
    appendTd(tr, adress + beacon.address + name + beacon.name);
    appendTd(tr, distance + beacon.rssi+" /"+beacon.txPower+"\u00A0"+beacon.estimatedDistance.toFixed(2)+'m', key);
    appendTd(tr, major + hex16(r.major)+"\u00A0"+ minor +hex16(r.minor));
    appendTd(tr, UUID + uint8ArrToHexStringNoSpace(r.uuid));
    root.appendChild(tr);
    
    
   } else {
    var td = document.getElementById(key);
    td.firstChild.nodeValue = 'Power: ' + beacon.rssi+"/"+beacon.txPower+ ' Distance: ' + "\u00A0"+beacon.estimatedDistance.toFixed(2)+'m';
   
   }
   
   if(beacon.address == '78:A5:04:13:3B:17' && beacon.estimatedDistance.toFixed(2) <= 10 ){
    something();
   }
   
   
  }, function(error) {
   console.log("startScan error: " + error);
  });
 },
};
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific as to where in this snippet of code the problem is...?

Comment: At a glance this sounds possible framework-specific. Can you tell us which conditional you would like to execute only once? Otherwise it's an intimidating amount of code to wade through!

Comment: How is this related to just Javascript? In any programming language, capture the state in a variable called actionPerformed = false which is initialized to false. once clicked set it to true. Once true, do a no-op.

Comment: almost at the end of the code I'm doing an if, which I call the function something, I need to call this function once

Comment: can be just window.open("info.html") once.

Answer (score 2):

use `localStorage`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

`localStorage` (and `sessionStorage`) let you keep persistent values

```
function something() {
    localStorage.setItem("somethingCalled", "yes");
    if(quit) {
       window.open("info.html");
    } 
    quit = true;
}
```

then where you call `something()`:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("somethingCalled")!="yes") { 
    something()
}
```

you may whant to use `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: it's weird, afaik nothing in ibeacon applications is against localStorage. can you give us more details about your platform?